# Erroneous example for aggregate intializaton?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, aggregate-initialization

The following example has been provided for aggregate initialization under [Direct Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)

```
struct A
{
    explicit A(int i = 0) {}
};
 
A a[2](A(1)); // OK: initializes a[0] with A(1) and a[1] with A()
A b[2]{A(1)}; // error: implicit copy-list-initialization of b[1]
              //        from {} selected explicit constructor
```

The above code which has been OKed in the example doesn't compile for me:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:14: error: converting to ‘A’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘A::A(int)’
    8 |   A a[2](A(1));
      |              ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

The following is my complete source code based on the above example:

```
struct A
{
  explicit A(int i = 0){}
};

int main (){

  A a[2](A(1));
  A b[2]{A(1)};

  return 0;
}
```

The compilation command I am using is as shown below (compiler version is `gcc 11.3.1`):

```
g++ -ggdb -g3 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -Wpedantic -std=c++20
```

Thoughts?

TIA

Comment: Note that this example is specific for the C++20 standard. Are you building with C++20 enabled? Please show the full and complete command you use to build, and tell us the compiler and version of it you use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited the question to provide the info

Comment: It's normally a warning but the `-pedantic-errors` flag turns it into an error. (See example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aMbch3KqM))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cppreference is correct, and GCC is wrong here. (But Clang gets it right. See [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x1P7s4Mh7).) This initialization is governed by [[dcl.init.general]/16.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.5):

> Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the object is initialized as follows. Let *x*<sub>1</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*k*</sub> be the elements of the *expression-list*. If the destination type is an array of unknown bound, it is defined as having *k* elements. Let *n* denote the array size after this potential adjustment. If *k* is greater than *n*, the program is ill-formed.
> Otherwise, the *i*th array element is copy-initialized with *x*<sub>*i*</sub> for each 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *k*, and value-initialized for each *k* < *i* ≤ *n*. For each 1 ≤ *i* < *j* ≤ *n*, every value computation and side effect associated with the initialization of the *i*th element of the array is sequenced before those associated with the initialization of the *j*th element.

There is no obstruction to value-initializing an object that has an explicit default constructor, except, as specified by [[over.match.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ctor#1), when the initialization is "in the context of copy-initialization", which is not the case here, since the direct-initialization syntax was used.

However, when you use aggregate initialization syntax, then any elements that don't have a specified initializer are copy-initialized from `{}`, so an explicit default constructor is not permitted to be selected in this context.

Answer (score 0):

By having:

```cpp
struct foo {
  explicit foo(int = 0) {} // this constructor
};
```

you implicitly delete the default constructor.
You have an `explicit` value constructor with a defaulted argument.
You can "fix" that by removing the default argument and adding a (explicit(false)) default constructor.

```cpp
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(int) {}
  Foo() = default;
};
```

[Live Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5xWv4GaEG)